# 500 Server error when initializing a class PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I am writing a database to  manage our clients a bit better.
The logic to show client data works flawlessly.

The class which handles my method calls is called "kunde"

Thats how I initialize the class and call the method to get some result array:

```
$showAllgemeineKundendaten = new kunde();
$result_array = $showAllgemeineKundendaten -> show_client_kundendaten($_SESSION['id'], 1);
```

I work with the result array in order to display the content - but thats a bit offtopic to my question.

**Now I am writing the logic to insert new clients to the database in another php document and I keep getting a 500 Server Error as soon as the class "kunde" is being initialized in the php file.**

I am currently sending a POST to this document with ajax :

```
    $gehrKundennummer = 0;
    $kundenklasse = 0;
    $lkw12t = 0;
    $lkw3t = 0;
    $autobus = 0;
    $firmenname1 = 0;
    $firmenname2 = 0;
    $uidnummer = 0;
    $peselregon = 0;
    $firmenart = 0;
    $strasse = 0;
    $ort = 0;
    $plz = 0;
    $land = 0;

    $gehrKundennummer = $_POST[0];
    $kundenklasse = $_POST[1];
    $lkw12t = $_POST[2];
    $lkw3t = $_POST[3];
    $autobus = $_POST[4];
    $firmenname1 = $_POST[5];
    $firmenname2 = $_POST[6];
    $uidnummer = $_POST[7];
    $peselregon = $_POST[8];
    $firmenart = $_POST[9];
    $strasse = $_POST[10];
    $ort = $_POST[11];
    $plz = $_POST[12];
    $land = $_POST[13];
    $data = array($gehrKundennummer, $kundenKlasse, $lkw12t, $lkw3t, $autobus, $firmenname1, $firmenname2, $uidnummer, $peselregon, $firmenart, $strasse, $ort, $plz, $land);
    $insert = new kunde();
    $insert -> insert_client($data, 1);
```

**NOTE** The 500 Server error occurs as well when the form is being sent to that php file the classic way.

And thats how my class and insert method looks like:

```
class kunde {
        public function insert_client($data, $case){
            $serverName = "SERVERNAME\MSSQLSRV";
            $connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'TEST', "UID"=>"TEST", "PWD"=>"TEST");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
            switch ($case) {
                case 1:
                    $gehrKundennummer = $data[0];
                    $kundenklasse = $data[1];
                    $lkw12t = $data[2];
                    $lkw3t = $data[3];
                    $autobus = $data[4];
                    $firmenname1 = $data[5];
                    $firmenname2 = $data[6];
                    $uidnummer = $data[7];
                    $peselregon = $data[8];
                    $firmenart = $data[9];
                    $strasse = $data[10];
                    $ort = $data[11];
                    $plz = $data[12];
                    $land = $data[13];
                    $angelegt_am = date();
                    $tsql = "INSERT INTO Kundendaten$ (gehr_kundennummer, kundenklasse_ID, firmenname1, firmenname2, firmenart, strasse, land, plz, ort, pesel_regon, uid, lkw12t, lkw3t, autobus, angelegt_am)
                            VALUES ('$gehrKundennummer', '$kundenklasse', '$firmenname1', '$firmenname2', '$firmenart', '$strasse', '$land', '$plz', '$ort', '$peselregon', '$lkw12t', '$lkw3t', '$autobus', '$angelegt_am')";
                    break;
                default:
                    # code...
                    break;
            }
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
            echo "done";
        }
// REST OF THE CLASS
}
```

When I am trying to initialize the class I get this error in the console:

```
POST http://#########/logic/add_client_logic.php 500 (Internal Server Error)jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4 m.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.11.2.min.js:4 m.extend.ajaxadd_client.js:21 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 m.event.dispatchjquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 m.event.add.r.handle
```

I am new to ajax so maybe I am doing something horribly wrong there?

Thats my js file content:

```
$(function (){
    var $allgSubmit = $('#allg_firmendaten_submit');
    $allgSubmit.click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
        event.preventDefault();
        var gehrKundennummer = $('#gehrKundennummer').val();
        var kundenklasse = $("input[type='radio'][name='kundenklasse']:checked").val();
        var lkw12t = $('#lkw12t').val();
        var lkw3t = $('#lkw3t').val();
        var autobus = $('#autobus').val();
        var firmenname1 = $('#firmenname1').val();
        var firmenname2 = $('#firmenname2').val();
        var uidnummer = $('#uidnummer').val();
        var peselregon = $('#peselregon').val();
        var firmenart = $('#firmenart option:selected').val();
        var strasse = $('#strasse').val();
        var ort = $('#ort').val();
        var plz = $('#plz').val();
        var land = $('#land').val();
        var allgArray = [ gehrKundennummer, kundenklasse, lkw12t, lkw3t, autobus, firmenname1, firmenname2, uidnummer, peselregon, firmenart, strasse, ort, plz, land ];
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://########/logic/add_client_logic.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $allgArray,
            success: function(){
                var $allgSave = $('#allgSave');
                $allgSave.toggle();
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: A 500 error will write to your error log. Look in your error log or `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` (if not on production). Also Javascript doesn't require a `$` for variable declaration.

Comment: I have ini_set('display_error',1); already ontop in my index.php

Where can I find the error log ?

Comment: It would be at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` if you're using Apache2 and didn't set to a custom location in php.ini

Comment: You really have a table called `Kundendaten$`? I am not sure about the exact rules for mysql tables, but you would need to escape it in your string at the very least.

Comment: I am using a windows server 2012 (so I dont know where the error logs are) with SQL installed, i am using SQLSRV extension to communicate with the server

I have imported an excel sheet into the Database , and thats how it got importet - it looks weird but works when i try to read data from the table

Comment: I can only give you tips on testing - clear code in your add_client_logic.php and just echo "1" from it and see if it works. I have a feeling because your are using absolute path for your file, the server gives you an error. It could be that the file is not accessible from the outside sources (and when you call it as a link, not as a relative path, such as /logic/add_client_logic.php) it thinks that someone else is trying to access your file.

Comment: If i echo anything it works - in the meaning of : The success callback function of ajax gets executed.
It also works if i remove the last two lines of my code 
That means that I get the 500 error with these lines :

$insert = new kunde();
    $insert -> insert_client($data, 1);

Comment: But the error even occurs as soon as i initialize the class - which means that the error isnt in the method but in the class "call" which is weird because ive used this class several times before without any problems

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The issue was simple and I blame myself for bothering you guys.

Since my logic file lies outside of the scope the class has never been included before initiliazing it == server error.

I simply included the class before executing my logic file and it works now.